# How to slide the next page in using CSS animations?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm trying to slide ut a title page and slide in a different page on a button click. My approach is to put both pages in `.slider`s in a `.slide-box` and attach `.slide-in` and `.slide-out` on click. I'm working in React so the functions `isSlidFirst` return div selector strings.

My issues are two. First, the width of the `.slider` element is inconsistent - the second slider is fully wide, as it is when the first isn't present, but the first is only as wide as the button and I can't figure out how to set the width independently of the width of the button! There's a significant area that's inaccessible between the end of the text and the beginning of the second `.slider`. Second, the second `.slider` doesn't slide in all the way. Screenshots at the bottom. I know I need to add `overflow: clip` but I've left it off so you can see what it's overflowing to.

I've got a skeleton layout like this:

```
    <div className="loader flex-center">                                                             
    <div className="do-stuff-box">                                                                   
    <div className="slide-box">                                                                      
      <div className={"slider first" + isSlidFirst()}>                                               
        <span className="main-header">                                                               
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Quo</span>                                                       
        <br/>                                                                                        
    <span className="sub-header">                                                                    
oluptas alias in perferendis omnis eos ipsam impedit et exercitationem voluptas 33 voluptatem dolores qui minima facere quo galisum consequuntur? Sed temporibus vero eos veritatis
    </span>                                                                                          
        <br/>                                                                                        
    <span className="main-header">Ready?</span>                                                      
        <div className="blue-button" onClick={() => setSlid(true)}>                                  
          Let's go                                                                                   
        </div>                                                                                       
        <div className="priv-terms">                                                                 
          <a href="/privacy">Privacy</a> and <a href="/terms">terms</a>.                             
        </div>                                                                                       
      </div>                                                                                         
      <div className={"slider second" + isSlidSecond()}>                                             
        <div className="input-area">                                                                 
          <div className="main-input-element">                                                       
            <span className="main-header">Put in a Google Sheets link!</span>       
            <input type="text"                                                                       
            value={spreadsheetLink}                                                                      
              onChange={(e) => setSpreadsheetLink(e.target.value)} />                                
          </div>                                                                                     
          <div id="hello" >                                                                          
                <GoogleButton props={{onClick: login, buttonIsEnabled: (!! parseLink(spreadsheetLink))}} />
          </div>                                                                               
          {recentSheetElements.length > 0 && (                                                       
            <>                                                                                       
            <h2>Your recent cards:</h2>                                                              
            {recentSheetElements}                                                                    
            </>                                                                                      
          )                                                                                          
          }                                                                                          
        </div>                                                                                       
      { spinnerActive &&                                                                             
        <Spinner/>                                                                                   
      }                                                                                              
      <div className="priv-terms" >                                                                  
          <a href="/privacy">How does this work?</a>                                                 
      </div>                                                                                         
    </div>                                                                                           
    </div>                                                                                           
    </div>                                                                                           
  </div>
```

with CSS

```
.slider {                                                                                            
  height: 100%;                                                                                      
  position: relative;                                                                                
  position: relative;                                                                                
  display: inline-block;                                                                             
}                                                                                                    
.slide-box {                                                                                         
    display: flex;                                                                                   
    width: 100%;                                                                                     
    height: 100%;                                                                                    
}                                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
.blue-button {                                                                                       
    background: cornflowerblue;                                                                      
    width: 300px;                                                                                    
    border-radius: 4px;                                                                              
    border: 2px solid darkgray;                                                                      
    height: 30px;                                                                                    
    display: flex;                                                                                   
    align-items: center;                                                                             
    justify-content: center;                                                                         
    margin: 10px;                                                                                    
}                                                                                                    
.second {                                                                                            
  transform: translateX(100%);                                                                       
}                                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
.slide-out {                                                                                         
  animation: slide-out 0.5s 1;                                                                       
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;                                                                     
}                                                                                                    
.slide-in {                                                                                          
  animation: slide-in 0.5s 1;                                                                        
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;                                                                     
}                                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
@keyframes slide-in {                                                                                
  0% { transform:  translateX(100%); }                                                               
  100% { transform: translateX(0%); }                                                                
}                                                                                           
@keyframes slide-out {                                                                                
  0% { transform:  translateX(0%); }                                                               
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }                                                                
}
```

[image: before the animation]

[image: after the animation]

Comment: Not fully supported yet, but the View Transitions API makes this easier: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/View_Transitions_API